# How to parse json response from two api calls with similar key and different values in a nested for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython-2.7

I have issue parsing the key and its values from api json response in a nested for loop with same key and different value with different two different api calls

I was able to get the key and values from api call, but the second api call with same key but different value has issue, throwing key error

```
def classtest(self):`enter code here`
    apione = http://jira.com/rest/1
    apitwo = https://jira.com/rest/2
    apithree = https://jira.com/rest/3  
    requestglobal = requests.request("GET", apione, content-type=application/json)
    responseglobal = requestglobal.getResponse()
    for i in responseglobal['issues']:
         issue1 = i[key]
         print(issue1)
         requesttwo = requests.request("GET", apithree, content-type=application/json)
         responsetwo = requestone.getResponse()
         for i in responsetwo['issues']:
               issue2 = i[key] + str(issue1)
               print(issue2)
               requestthree = requests.request("GET", apitthree, content-type=application/json)
               responsethree = requestthree.getResponse()
               for i in responsethree['issues']:
                     issue3 = i[key] + str(issue2) 
                     print(issue3)
         print("something from second loop") 
    print ("something from first for loop")
```

Now it is working for the first call , but failing on second call throwing `keyError` it should return both issue1 and issue2 values.

Comment: what is `key` defined as? also they both come from jira so you shouldn't need more than a single for loop

Comment: Where have you defined key? Looks like it is in the first api response but not the second. You might want to avoid calling your function 'class' as class is a different type of object in python. Also your function is twice as long as it needs to be, you can can write it so that it deals with both apione and apitwo but calling the function twice rather than having double the amount of code in the function. What does it return?

Comment: key is from both api responses.  first api has response as [{issues{key: value}}] and the second api also has respose as [{issues{key : value2}}], basically i am doing api call to jira, and running two different queries ,both has similar responses with different issue id`s